# Horizontal bar plots using coord_flip() - need left aligned values in bars

Tags: ggplot2

I've been fighting to get this plot matrix just right. It uses a combination of ggplot2() and patchwork() to bring it all together. But, right now the values inside the bars are right aligned, and I need them to be left aligned.

Here's what I'm getting now:

[Horizontal Bar plots with right aligned text inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUb3U.png)

Here's how I want the plots to look:

[Horizontal Bar plot with left aligned text inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRUmk.png)

Simplified version of code below:

```
    if (!require('tidyverse')) install.packages('tidyverse'); library('tidyr')
if (!require('ggplot2')) install.packages('ggplot2'); library('ggplot2')
if (!require('ggthemes')) install.packages('ggthemes'); library('ggthemes')
if (!require('patchwork')) install.packages('patchwork'); library('patchwork')

#######################################################
Generate data on a hypothetical individual with means

#######################################################
one_person <-
  data.frame(Category = c("perf_driven"),
             old_average = sample(800:900, 1, replace = TRUE),
             self_eval = sample(700:800, 1, replace = TRUE),
             mgr_eval = sample(700:800, 1, replace = TRUE),
             peer_eval = sample(700:800, 1, replace = TRUE)
  )

################################################
Horizontal bar plots

################################################

horizontal_bars <- function(data_object,metric) {
  .e<-pivot_longer(data_object, -Category, names_to = "Survey", values_to = "Score")

  .e <- .e %>%
    subset(Category==metric)

  ggplot(.e,aes(Category, Score, fill = Survey)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE, padding=0), width = .5) +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(label=Score), position=position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE, width=.5), hjust=1.1, size = 2.5) +
    #geom_text(aes(label = Score, hjust=0)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "none",
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)
    )

}

################################################
Theme for transparency

################################################

transparent_bg_theme =
  theme(
    # panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), # bg of the panel
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA), # bg of the plot
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), # get rid of legend bg
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")

  )

##################################################
Create plots and plot matrix (the real version has all different plots)

##################################################

a1 <- horizontal_bars(one_person,"perf_driven")

widths = c(.8,.8)
height = .5
plot_matrix = a1 + a1 +
  a1 + a1 +
  a1 + a1 +
  a1 + a1 +
  a1 + a1

plot_matrix = plot_matrix + plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 5, widths = widths, heights = height)
plot_matrix <- plot_matrix & transparent_bg_theme

##################################################
Output png file

##################################################

ggsave('matrix_example.png', plot = plot_matrix, height=7, width=2.5, units="in", dpi="print", type="cairo", bg = 'transparent')
```

Thanks so much for your help! I've been fighting with this for too many hours and really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your ggplot2 calls, your `geom_text()` function is inheriting the value of `Score` to be the y location.  I would put `Score` as a local y aesthetic for `geom_bar()` and then provide a static y value (of maybe 100 and hjust=0) for `geom_text()`.  In other words,

```
ggplot( .e, aes(Category, fill=Score) ) +
  geom_bar( aes(y=Score), stat="identity", ... ) +
  geom_text( aes(label=Score), y=100, hjust=0, ... ) +
  ...
```

Comment: This solution was so simple, I can't believe I didn't figure it out myself. Thank you so much statstew!